# Snowflake stored procedure taking iterative values from column

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need some inputs on how to read the values of a column and make them available for forming a SQL and executing in Snowflake.

Multiple values are present in the table "all_resource_monitor_master"

```
SELECT 'RM'||'_'||rm_type||'_'||env INTO lv_rm_name FROM all_resource_monitor_master;      ---> The o/p of this can be stored in a table.

  <My loop starts based on lv_rm_name>
 
   rm_setup := 'CREATE RESOURCE MONITOR IF NOT EXISTS ' || ' ' || '"' || <lv_rm_name> || '"' || ' ' || 'WITH' || ' '
              || 'CREDIT_QUOTA = ' || ' ' || lv_credit_quota || ' ' 
              || 'FREQUENCY = ' || ' ' || '"' || lv_frequency || '"' || ' '
              || 'START_TIMESTAMP = ' || ' ' || '"' || lv_timestamp || '"'|| ' '
              || 'NOTIFY_USERS = ' || '(' || '"' || lv_notify_users || '"' || ')' || ' '
              || 'TRIGGERS ON ' || lv_trigger1 || ' ' || 'PERCENT DO ' || ' ' || lv_action1 || ' '
              ||          'ON ' || lv_trigger2 || ' ' || 'PERCENT DO ' || ' ' || lv_action2 || ' '
              ||          'ON ' || lv_trigger3 || ' ' || 'PERCENT DO ' || ' ' || lv_action3 || ' ';
  
  execute immediate :rm_setup;

  <My loop ends based on lv_rm_name>
```

Please do share the inputs on how to achieve this functionality by using the loops.

Comment: Recommend you review the snowflake docs on scripting with loops: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/loops.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I have addressed this now !!